# SPA Authentication on multiple cards

Tags: c#, asp.net, vue.js

I should implement an authentication on several tabs for my SPA, so that it can authenticate us with different users on different tabs of the same browser.
(eg how does GMAIL if you have multiple accounts).

I don't know what approach to take, do you have any suggestions about it?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [how-to-ask article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. Please tell us what you already tried, show some code an error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably keep the authentication state into Vuex. For the tab sync, there are some packages that may be useful here: https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#sync-between-tabs

If you want to have several authenticated users, you may think about some logic to handle it into your localStorage or alike. But this kind of question is out of scope (opinion-based) and would be closed. If you want to achieve this, come back with some code sample that you've already tried.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I saw you sent me some packages that use vuejs.
Are you using it?
How are you?

Comment: I'm not using them personally but `vuex-shared-mutations` looks to have quite some people behind the repo, so you should not worry too much about diving into them IMO. :)